# jQuery alert resetting the focus to different element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this fiddle, when I press tab, the focus should be set on next element, but its not..
Here's the code..

```
<input type="text" style="font-size:12px;width:245px;" border-style="Solid" tabindex="3" id="txtCAddress" maxlength="100" name="txtCAddress" />
</br>

<input type="text" style="font-size:12px;width:245px;" border-style="Solid" tabindex="4" id="txtMobile" name="txtMobile"/>

</br>

<input type="text" style="font-size:12px;width:245px;" border-style="Solid" id="txtPriority" maxlength="300" name="txtPriority" tabindex="5" autocomplete="off" />
```

The js is

```
$(document).ready(function(event) {
    $('#txtCAddress').keydown(function(e) {
        if ((e.which == 9)) {
            if ($('#txtCAddress').val() == '') {
                alert('me');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

When I press tab in `txtCAddress` with some text, its okay, the focus is getting set on `txtMobile` as excepted, but when I press tab in `txtCAddress` without any text, the alert is coming fine, but the focus is getting set on `txtPriority`?

Why is the focus not on `txtMobile`?

**EDIT**
The js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sXaMG/1/

Comment: That's not happening for me in the fiddle - txtMobile gets the focus after closiung the alert.  I only tested in IE9.

Comment: @AlanShortis. Same with chrome.

Comment: @gdoron. Same with Firefox. Working.

Comment: @AlanShortis:
Working in IE8 too...

Comment: @Razort4x. So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: ...and in Opera, Safari and IE7.

Comment: @AlanShortis:
What about FF? I tested in ver 15 and 16?

Comment: OK - just checked FF 15 and I see your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use alert() in keydown function callback as its override event default behaviour, use console.log() instead.
From that, seems to work perfectly.

Comment: So, why is it working in IE 8, IE9, opera? and safari? And just not firefox?